# Integrity error with django user model

Tags: python, django

[image]

I'm working through https://bixly.com/blog/awesome-forms-django-crispy-forms/ , trying to set up a bootstrap 3 form using django crispy forms.

in app1/models.py, I have set up my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django import forms


class User(AbstractUser):

    # Address
    contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact_address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact_email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ......
```

app1/forms.py:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = User # Your User model
            fields = ['contact_name', 'contact_address', 'contact_email', 'contact_phone']

        helper = FormHelper()
        helper.form_method = 'POST'
        helper.form_action = "/contact/"
        helper.form_id = 'form' # SET THIS OR BOOTSTRAP JS AND VAL.JS WILL NOT WORK
        helper.add_input(Submit('Submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-primary'))
```

app1/views.py:

```
def contact(request):

    django_query_dict = request.POST
    message = django_query_dict.dict()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "im in contact "+str(message)
        form = UserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            print('invalid')
```

I've been able to get it working for the first record (screenshot above). However because I'm using/extending the user model I'm running into problems with the built in user registration functionality. When I try to add a second record I get:

```
Exception Type: IntegrityError at /contact/
Exception Value: column username is not unique
 Request information:
 GET: No GET data
```

I can see that this is true because I am not getting data for username in the form, so a blank will be entered both the first and second record causing the integrity error the second time. How can I fix this. Should I even be using the built in user model?

Comment: Does any other model has username field?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand the question.

Comment: I think you should avoid writing a record to database if username is empty. May be you should add some validation logic to your code to check if all the mandatory columns are filled and are unique before creating a record for the user. That can be done handling the Integrity Error (try except block) and throw a error back to user/front end if it causes integrity error.